# python django exception handling

Tags: python, django, exception

I have a query where I used exception:

```
try:
    sm = Something.objects.get(id=5)
except Something.DoesNotExist:
    pass
```

Here what does pass do ? I mean what if my whole view depends on `sm` and it does not get `sm` . Should I set "sm" manually like:

```
except Something.DoesNotExist:
    sm = anything
```

I just want to know what do pass do if it dont find whats queried. If it just ignore the part after except and go further then whats the point because my whole view depends on `sm`

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The keyword `pass` in the above context ignores `DoesNotExist` exception. If your program depends on the existence of `sm` somewhere down in your code, you should set it to `None` and check its value where you need it.

```
try:
    sm = Something.objects.get(id=5)
except Something.DoesNotExist:
    sm = None

if sm:
    ...
```

Alternatively, you can do your job in the `else` part of your try/catch block. It is executed only when the code in `try` block doesn't raise an exception.

```
try:
    sm = Something.objects.get(id=5)
except Something.DoesNotExist:
    # do something here..
else:
    print sm
    ...
```

Comment: Also, if you just want to through a 404 exception if this Something isn't found, use this instead: `something = get_object_or_404(Something, id=5)`

Comment: can I set default value if the object is not found in except. like except Something.DoesNotExist:
    sm = "someone"

Comment: AFAIK, Django doesn't provide a shortcut method for this case but, of course you can do it in Python. However, if you have a default value already, I'd recommend you to set it somewhere above try/catch for the sake of code readability. You can write some method like `get_object_or_default(Something, id=5, default="someone")`.

Comment: ohk then what about this like I want to use a property of sm like sm.phone_no if I dont get sm then how can I set default value for phone_no of sm

Comment: You can't use an instance (_sm_ in this case) property unless instance is created. You should set the default value for phone number as a `class property`, maybe something like `Something.DEFAULT_PHONE_NO`, so you'll be able to use it even when `sm` isn't created.

Answer (score 0):

[`pass` is a null statement that does nothing](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#pass-statements), and is useful when you need a statement due to indentation rules, but don't want to write the code yet.

If you removed it to have the code:

```
try:
    sm = Something.objects.get(id=5)
except Something.DoesNotExist:
```

It would fail with a syntax error.

---

As for what to do if you don't find the item you are looking for, that very much depends on the rest of the code. However, in a case like this it would be better to show an error to *someone* as thats what has happened - you've requested an item that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

`pass` is the `no-op` and does nothing.  It need to be in the `except` block to conform python syntax.